# Visual Studio 2022 TypeScript code highlights / coloring

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2022

I gave a try using TypeScript in Visual Studio 2022 (instead of VSCode), to develop both backend and frontend in the same environment.
It seems to work fine, but for some reason TypeScript code misses proper code highlighting, like displaying methods in yellow.
VS2022 supposedly has full support of JavaScript/TypeScript and even has Angular templates. Am I missing something, or are there some extensions to make the code prettier?

VS2022 example
[image: VS2022 example]

VSCode example
[image: VSCode example]

Comment: comparing VS and VSC for syntax highlighting is the same as comparing VS and vim for syntax highlighting, they are completely different beasts

Comment: Yes, I can see that. Do you know if it's possible to make a custom extension to change and improve syntax coloring for specific language? I've only seen how to create a completely new one, for a language otherwise not supported at all.